# Is there a method to clone DateTime value which has same date but different hour and minute from the original one?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, clone

I have time values of hour and minute stored in database. I want to use them to create a period; "start time" and "end time". Both time have the same date but different hour and minutes. Here is the code I'm using right now to copy start time properties to end time.

```
Dim endTime As New DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, endHour, endMinute, 0)
```

(endHour and endMinute are **exact** hour and minute properties of end time)

I just want to know if there is a better way than this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets only the year, month and day from `startTime` with default values for the rest:

```
Dim endTime As Date = startTime.Date
```

Then you can add the rest of the values that you need in the way you want, for example:

```
endTime = endTime.AddHours(endHour)
endTime = endTime.AddMinutes(endMinute)
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

And to to it in one line, you can do something like this:

```
Dim endTime As Date = startTime.Date.AddHours(endHour).AddMinutes(endMinute)
```

Or even:

```
Dim endTime As Date = startTime.Date.AddMinutes(endHour * 60 + endMinute)
```

But your approach is Ok too, tought.

Comment: `DateTime` is immutable, so both `DateTime.Hour` and `DateTime.Minutes` are read-only properties.

Comment: No it isn't. `AddHours` and `AddMinutes` returns new `DateTime` object without changing existing one. So you can't use it just like `endTime.AddHours()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's my fault for not explaining clearly (I have edited my question a bit now). Both endHour and endMinute are exact values, not additional values from start time so what I'm looking for is the method which can "set" hour and minute rather than adding them. But I got an idea from all of you here so thanks anyway.

Comment: @PawichS. If you have hour 0 and add 7 then hour turns into 7. And as I explain, the `Datetime.Date` property gets only Year, Month and Day leaving the Hour and minutes with default (`0`) values.

Comment: Oh! That's it. I didn't see .Date part. My fault again -_-"
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use:

[DateTime.AddHours Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx)

[DateTime.AddMinutes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx)

to get the "End DateTime"

Comment: Well, actually I don't really want "adding" method since I want to set the exact value of end time's hour and minute. But now I know how to apply these methods you provided. Before using these method I have to subtract the value from start date. Thanks for suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim endTime As Date = startTime.Date.AddHours(endHour).AddMinutes(endMinute)
```

I'm not sure it's more readable or better in any other way, but maybe you find it better.

Comment: Oh, Sorry for not clearly explained. endHour and endMinute are not additional values from start date but they are exact values. But I can apply this method by subtracting the value from start date. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: 'startTime.Date` takes only year, month and day leaving all time-related values with 0, so adding `endHours` sets that hour.

Comment: ...as I clearly explained on my answer that was the first one.